# How to change the applet name using Jquery

Tags: jquery, applet

Using JQuery when I try to update the Applet name it is creating a new attribute "submitName" instead of updating the existing applet name. How can I update the Applet name? I am able to update the Applet Ids successfully.

Here is my applet:

```
<APPLET NAME="Test1" id="GridRow1" CODEBASE="/XMII/Classes" CODE="iGrid" ARCHIVE="illum8.zip" style="font-size: 10pt; width: 342px; display: inline; height: 72px;" align="top"> </APPLET>
```

Here is my JQuery Code:

```
$('#' + curRowId).clone().attr('id',newRowId).insertAfter($('#' + curRowId));
```

After cloning is done, I am updating the Ids and name of the .

```
$('#' + newRowId).find('*').each(function () {
                if(parseFloat(newRowNum) <= 4()){
                    $(this).attr("id", String($(this).attr("id")).substr(0,String($(this).attr("id")).length-1) + newRowNum);
                    newAppletName = String($(this).attr("name"));
                    if (newAppletName != "undefined") { 
                        $(this).attr("name", newAppletName.substr(0, String(newAppletName).length-1) + newRowNum);
                    }
                }
        });
```

Comment: add your code please ?

Comment: Here is my Applet:  <APPLET NAME="Test1" id="GridRow1" CODEBASE="/XMII/Classes" CODE="iGrid" ARCHIVE="illum8.zip" style="font-size: 10pt; width: 342px;  display: inline; height: 72px;" align="top">
    
   </APPLET>

Comment: where? i am unable to see

Comment: Here is my JQuery Code: After cloning is done, I am updating the Ids and name of the tds.   $('#' + curRowId).clone().attr('id',newRowId).insertAfter($('#' + curRowId));

Comment: $('#' + newRowId).find('*').each(function () {
    if(parseFloat(newRowNum) <= 4()){
     $(this).attr("id", String($(this).attr("id")).substr(0,String($(this).attr("id")).length-1) + newRowNum);
     newAppletName = String($(this).attr("name"));
     if (newAppletName != "undefined") { 
      $(this).attr("name", newAppletName.substr(0, String(newAppletName).length-1) + newRowNum);
     }
    }
  });

Comment: Don't dump code into comment blocks. Update the question with properly formatted code and clarifications